# Python3 ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Fast Global Image Smoothing Based on Weighted Least Squares
In this paper, the global smoothing problem is mainly transformed into a weighted quadratic energy function, which minimizes the energy function to achieve the smoothness of the image, and this optimization problem can be transformed into a solving problem of a linear equation system. There are obvious advantages in solution efficiency and solution time, and this is also a globally optimal linear system.

This assignment is mainly for the basic algorithm of the paper.Separable global smoother for 2D iamge smoothingReproduced, using the python language, in order to speed up the calculation, use mxnet.ndarray to perform operations on the CPU.

This assignment is mainly for the basic algorithm of the paper.Separable global smoother for 2D iamge smoothingReproduced, using the python language, in order to speed up the calculation, use mxnet.ndarray to perform operations on the GPU

I have a problem with my Python 3 program. I use Window 10. This code is running properly.

```py
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet import nd
import numpy as np
import warnings
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
def cw_1d(p, q, g, sigma):
    norm = nd.norm(g[p] - g[q])
    return nd.exp(-norm/sigma)

def compute_lamb(t, T, lamb_base):
    return 1.5 * 4**(T-t) / (4 ** T - 1) * lamb_base

def compute_1d_fast_global_smoother(lamb, f, g, sigma, ctx):
    w = f.shape[0]
    _c = nd.zeros(shape=w-1, ctx=ctx)
    _c[0] = -lamb * cw_1d(0, 1, g, sigma) / (1 + lamb * cw_1d(0, 1, g, sigma))
    _f = nd.zeros(shape=f.shape, ctx=ctx)
    _f[0] = f[0] / (1 + lamb * cw_1d(0, 1, g, sigma))

    for i in range(1, w-1):
        _c[i] = -lamb * cw_1d(i, i + 1, g, sigma) / (
            1 + lamb * (cw_1d(i, i - 1, g, sigma) + cw_1d(i, i + 1, g, sigma)) +
            lamb * _c[i - 1] * cw_1d(i, i - 1, g, sigma))
        _f[i] = (f[i] + _f[i - 1] * lamb * cw_1d(i, i - 1, g, sigma)) / (
            1 + lamb * (cw_1d(i, i - 1, g, sigma) + cw_1d(i, i + 1, g, sigma)) +
            lamb * _c[i - 1] * cw_1d(i, i - 1, g, sigma))
    _f[w-1] = (f[w-1] + _f[w-2] * lamb * cw_1d(w-1, w-2, g, sigma)) / (
            1 + lamb * (cw_1d(w-1, w-2, g, sigma)) +
            lamb * _c[w-2] * cw_1d(w-1, w-2, g, sigma))
    u = nd.zeros(shape=f.shape, ctx=ctx)
    u[w - 1] = _f[w - 1]

    for i in range(w - 2, -1, -1):
        u[i] = _f[i] - _c[i] * u[i + 1]
    return u.asnumpy()

x1 = np.random.normal(scale=0.2, size=(100))
x2 = np.random.normal(4, 0.2, size=(100))
x = np.concatenate((x1, x2))
plt.plot(np.arange(x.shape[0]), x)

u = compute_1d_fast_global_smoother(900, nd.array(x, ctx=mx.cpu(0)), nd.array(x, mx.cpu(0)), 0.07, mx.cpu(0))
plt.plot(np.arange(u.shape[0]), u)

def Separable_global_smoother(f, T, lamb_base, sigma, ctx):

    print('origin lamb is {}'.format(lamb_base))
    print('sigma is {}'.format(sigma))
    H, W, C = f.shape
    u = f.copy()
    for t in range(1, T+1):
        lamb_t = compute_lamb(t, T, lamb_base)
        for y in range(0, W):
            g = u[:, y, :]
            for c in range(C):
                f_h = u[:, y, c]
                u[:, y, c] = compute_1d_fast_global_smoother(lamb_t, f_h, g, sigma, ctx)
        # vertical
        for x in range(0, H):
            g = u[x, :, :]
            for c in range(C):
                f_v = u[x, :, c]
                u[x, :, c] = compute_1d_fast_global_smoother(lamb_t, f_v, g, sigma, ctx)
    return u
```

Problems starts when I am trying to add value to the Iteration.

```py
origin_img = Image.open('C:/Users/蔡晉易天蔡之蔡總統/Desktop/MSRA10K_Imgs_GT - 複製 (3)/img_ (1).jpg')

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.title('origin image')
plt.imshow(origin_img)

img_100 = origin_img.resize((100, 100))
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.title('50 x 50 image')
plt.imshow(img_100)

lamb_base = 30**2
sigma = 255 * 0.03
ctx = mx.cpu(0)
img = np.array(img_100)
img = nd.array(img, ctx=ctx)

T = 1
u1 = Separable_global_smoother(img, T, lamb_base, sigma, ctx)
show_u = u1.astype('uint8').asnumpy()
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.title('1 iteration smooth result')
plt.imshow(show_u)
```

Terminal shows error:

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ff6f57019d54> in <module>
      1 T = 1
----> 2 u1 = Separable_global_smoother(img, T, lamb_base, sigma, ctx)
      3 show_u = u1.astype('uint8').asnumpy()
      4 plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
      5 plt.title('1 iteration smooth result')

<ipython-input-7-468a27edeff0> in Separable_global_smoother(f, T, lamb_base, sigma, ctx)
      6     print('origin lamb is {}'.format(lamb_base))
      7     print('sigma is {}'.format(sigma))
----> 8     H, W, C = f.shape
      9     u = f.copy()
     10     for t in range(1, T+1):

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Comment: `f` (which, in your call is `image`) is bidimensional (one channel image?), so `f.shape` is a list `[H, W]`, which you try to unpack in three values. Hence the error.

Comment: f is 2D image, 3 channels

Comment: If you `print(f.shape)` before the line that raises the error, what does it say?

Comment: same error "not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)"